# How to create a DataFrame if the executor nodes do not have python

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Due to a limitation in the hadoop cluster I am using with YARN, the execute nodes do not have python.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([[0]], ['foo'])
print(df)
df.collect()
```

```
DataFrame[foo: bigint]
... java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory
```

It is not an issue of properly setting `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` as the execute nodes do not have a python interpreter at all. I am wondering if there is a java python extension or some other way of converting data into a dataframe to pass to the cluster.

Comment: I may be missing something but 1/ why do you want to use Python if your machines don't have Python? 2/ why can't you install Python? It's almost always available.

Comment: 1. My edge node has python. The server compute nodes do not
2. Getting lots of pushback from the cluster admins.